# how to access result outside the loop

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

i am not able to access variable outside the  SearchData.forEach loop here is my code

```
 SearchDataJson =[]; 
var searchdataArray = [];  
 SearchData.forEach( async function(item){ 
 var sql = "SELECT email , mobile from user_profile where id in (228,192) limit 2"; 
 var tempData = function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      pool.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(results);
      });
    });
  };   
  await tempData().then( async function(results) { 
     SearchDataJson.push({KeyTags:item.hashtags,Data:results}); 
  });
  console.log(SearchDataJson);
});
```

Comment: There are many npm packages that have that idea of **pool.query**. Although based on your error message is possible to detect that you are trying to do that by using MySQL, the title itself does not say that and that does not make it very useful for other users with the same problem to search and find your question with the possible answers. If you could please update the title and also give a better description including the version of nodejs, operating system, the version of the MySQL package and the snipped of code of how you are creating the **pool** variable.

Comment: Actually my main problem in i am not able to access variable outside the  loop  , my whole result generated in loop but i am not able to get that result variable out side the loop    var searchdataArray = [];  
     SearchData.forEach( async function(item){   SearchDataJson.push({KeyTags:item.hashtags,Data:results}); }); this SearchDataJson variable want to access out side the foreach function